# Custom SQL Query for Wordpress page

Tags: pages, mysql

I'm quite new to wordpress.
I'm trying to build a tableview within a wordpress page. Therfore I need a custom SQL Query to my MySQL Database.

1. Query data from my MySQL Database
2. Get the result somehow in a HTML format in order to display it in a table view within a wordpress page.

My question is:
How can I use the wpdb_class in a wordpress page when it is not an option to put php code in a page?

Comment: Use the [`wpdb class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for custom queries in wordpress. You may also want to try the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Telling us that you want to pull data from MySQL into a WordPress page is too vague for you to get any useful help.

Comment: [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) Check the Codex page for [`shortcodes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to start. This question is pretty broad and looks like several questions in one. See also: [how to ask a good question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've edited my question and I know that the wpdb_class is somehow the answer, but where do I need to put the php code that is required in order to use the wpdb_class. As I guess it needs to be placed somewhere outside of the wordpress page, I need to get the results somehow transferred from that place to the wordpress page.

Comment: You can either [write a WordPress plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), or you can insert your code into [your theme's `functions.php` file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).  Allowing PHP code to be added directly in the WP editor is a security nightmare, to put it mildly.

Comment: @Pat J: So let's say I've created my plugin the way it's described. How do I now display the query result of that plugin on a wordpress page?

Answer (score 11):

The `wpdb` object can be used to [run arbitrary queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database) against the WordPress database.  Let's say you want to list the most recent 4 posts:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE `post_type`='post' LIMIT 4" );
```

The `$wpdb->posts` variable will output the table name for posts.  It's usually `wp_posts`, but if you're using a custom database prefix this could be different.

However, if you're trying to grab post data (or custom post data or meta information or user data or ... anything built-in to WordPress), you should really be using [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Here's the same query above, re-written for `WP_Query`:

```
$query = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 4
    )
);
```

The advantage of using `WP_Query` is that it will automatically join against the post meta table and return an array of `WP_Post` objects that you can work with and loop through.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$post_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'mfn-post-link1' AND meta_value = '". $from ."')");
    print_r($post_id); /
?>
```

Define global variable $wpdb then make custom query and pass $wpdb->get_results();

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: With this query you can use in any where at the wordpress for get data into wordpress