# Wordpress plugins for database queries

Tags: mysql

I have a handful of custom database commands that my admin users need to execute on an adhoc basis - it's some business logic that was unavailable in a normal plugin. The commands are all procedures that either execute successfully, or return a record set.

I want to be able to make these commands available through the Wordpress admin interface, ideally saving each query with a friendly name (eg Process1 - start of day) so that it is easier to execute but I haven't been able to find a solution. The admin users are slightly horrified by the likes of PHPMyAdmin for Wordpress, or even using SSH to get to a Bash menu script which executes database commands when options are selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a plugin that allows you to do this out of the box, but as you are (/seem to be) comfortable with database manipulation, I've outlined below how you can achieve what you want using custom coding.

You can run custom queries using the [`wpdb`-class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). There are [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158523/running-custom-sql-in-pre-existing-wordpress-plugin) [few](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98211/custom-sql-query-for-wordpress-page) [posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/63958/how-to-execute-sql-select-query-and-see-the-results) on WPSE/SO that treat this. Once you've set those up, you can run them on, for example, a custom admin page (a new page in the Wordpress Dashboard). There are various tutorials available online (such as [this one](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-custom-admin-pages-in-wordpress-1--cms-26829)) that show how that can be done.